# regular expression to take two line

Tags: regex

i have a line like:

```
ERROR: file' user\username\file\myfile.mp3' c
annot be used, because required software is not installed.
Follow the given instruction below
instruction one.............
```

i want a regular expression which will cover

```
first two line that means from "ERROR" to "is not installed".
```

i use the below

```
(ERROR\:[^\.]+\.?)
```

but it takes only

```
ERROR: file' user\username\file\myfile
```

any kind of help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? Most have a "multi-line" mode where (for example) `^` will match the start of the input (rather than start of a line.

Comment: @Richard actually i verify it on https://regex101.com/ website and i am doing it on windows for powershell

Comment: input is not same always ...... there are any other string rather than input

Comment: The trouble is, there is a period in the filename. Is the empty line reliable?

Comment: What are you assuming `[^.]` does?  It matches any character which is not a (newline or) a literal dot.

Comment: Does this work for you `ERROR:(?:.*\s*){2}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\bERROR:[\s\S]*?\.(?=[\r\n])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP5qG8/2)

It starts matching with text `ERROR:` and matches everything including newline characters until a DOT is found just before a newline.

Answer (score 1):

If we can rely on the format of there being an empty line after the desired message, we could use that to capture the message itself:

[`/ERROR\:[\W\w]*?(?=\r?\n\r?\n)/`](https://regex101.com/r/mT1nJ1/1)

- `ERROR\:` Literal text.
- `[\W\w]*?` Matches any character zero or more times, but as few times as possible. This means it will match up to whatever should come next.
- `(?=\r?\n\r?\n)` Matches if the following characters make up an empty line. (But doesn't include that text as part of the match itself.)

Comment: your answer is ok but i put mistakenly a new line. as i removed new line it takes all .... can you please check it again and do me a favor so that i can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

By using [`java.util.regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String line = "ERROR: file' user\\username\\file\\myfile.mp3' c\n"+
                    "annot be used, because required software is not installed.\n\n"+
                    "Follow the given instruction below\n"+
                    "instruction one.............\n";

      String regex = "^ERROR: [A-Za-z0-9\\.,'\\s\\\\\n]+(?=\\s{2})";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
      if(matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(line);
         System.out.println(matcher.group(0) );
      }
}
```

You'll get:

```
ERROR: file' user\username\file\myfile.mp3' c
annot be used, because required software is not installed.

Follow the given instruction below
instruction one.............

ERROR: file' user\username\file\myfile.mp3' c
annot be used, because required software is not installed.
```

For [regex101.com](https://regex101.com):

```
^ERROR: [A-Za-z0-9\\.,'\s\\\n]+(?=\s{2})
```

See result here: https://regex101.com/r/sL8vQ3/1

Comment: its not working , if you see it in regex101.com , you will see

Comment: sorry, its not working in regex101.com, copy my lines and paste it to that site , than use your solution hope you will find the difference.